# Number of binary words that form a group of Hamming weight at most d

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory, algebra, group-theory, hamming-distance

Consider binary words in {0,1}^n whose Hamming weight is at most some constant d. We want to select some of these words such that they form a group under addition. How many words can we choose at most?

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is known as a *group anticode* with maximal distance $d$. The obvious construction is to take all vectors of the form $(x_1,\ldots,x_d,0,\ldots,0)$, obtaining a group of size $2^d$. Ahlswede, [Another diametric theorem in Hamming spaces: optimal group anticodes](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/ahlswede/homepage/public/212.pdf) showed that this is optimal, and furthermore, the solution I described is unique up to isomorphism, except when $d = 2$, in which case another solution is $(0,0,0,\bar{0}),(1,1,0,\bar{0}),(1,0,1,\bar{0}),(0,1,1,\bar{0})$.

Comment: Great help. Thanks.